# Backbone Dynamically Save Property

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I'm attempting to save a dynamic property to a backbone model.

So basically a `question` could have a question_type of say `"car"` or `"house_type"`.

Ideally I'd like to do something like this:
`@appuser.save(question.get('question_type'): answer.get('answer_number'))`

Where `question.get('question_type')` dynamically shifts to `@appuser.save(car: answer.get('answer_number'))` or `@appuser.save(house_type: answer.get('answer_number'))`

I tried doing `question_type = question.get('question_type')` and then `@appuser.save(question_type: answer.get('answer_number'))` but that actually just sets `question_type` for the appuser.

An example of how I would do this in Rails would be to do a `appuser.update_attributes("#{question_type}" => value)` which would dynamically convert question_type to `car` or what have you.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I've been able to just store these values in a string and save that to `question_type` and parse it out appropriately on my server. But I'd still prefer to find a way to handle it dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save) for `.save` you'll notice that you can pass a hash of attributes.

Since you can create objects with dynamic keys you can first create the data you want to set and then pass it to `.save`

```
var attrs = {};
attrs[question.get('question_type')] = answer.get('answer_number');
@appuser.save(attrs);
```